# How to use features for training neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I downloaded a dataset for intrusion detection. It's from the [honeypot systems of Kyoto University](http://www.takakura.com/Kyoto_data/new_data201704/) (2013 dataset). I'll be using the dataset for training a neural network. My problem is how to process the dataset. Am I going to use vector space model or what?

A sample from the dataset:

`0.000000,other,0,0,0,0.00,0.00,0.00,1,37,1.00,0.00,0.00,RSTOS0,0,0,0,1,fd75:41fb:cf76:971a:0b40:03a2:4ab7:0f81,38581,fd75:41fb:cf76:dc4c:7d2c:2705:07b2:0f45,25,00:00:00,tcp`

The specifications of the features are as follows ([further details](http://www.takakura.com/Kyoto_data/BenchmarkData-Description-v5.pdf)):

1. Duration
2. Service
3. Source bytes
4. Destination bytes
5. Count
6. Same_srv_rate
7. Serror_rate
8. Srv_serror_rate
9. Dst_host_count
10. Dst_host_srv_count
11. Dst_host_same_src_port_rate
12. Dst_host_serror_rate
13. Dst_host_srv_serror_rate
14. Flag
15. IDS_detection
16. Malware_detection
17. Ashula_detection
18. Label
19. Source_IP_Address
20. Source_Port_Number
21. Destination_IP_Address
22. Destination_Port_Number
23. Start_Time
24. Duration

Comment: If it is a publicly available dataset, i doubt that you are the first one to work on it. I recommend to read papers on how others preprocessed the same dataset

Comment: Thanks, @NikolasRieble I did read one paper, the other night. What they did was to index the symbolic features like `service` to [0, n-1] where n is the number of symbols. As for the integer values, they did a linear scaling to [0.0, 1.0]. What I am now having a trouble with is how they did the linear scaling.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a linear scaling here means first $x_i = x_i - min_i(x_i)$ and the $x_i = x_i / max_i(x_i)$ for all values.

Comment: I actually defined it as a function $f(x) = \frac{(b - a) \times (x - min)}{(max - min)} + a$ where $[min, max] \rightarrow [a, b]$.

Comment: $[a, b]$ is the scale range, for my problem, it's $[0.0, 1.0]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the categorical data like `service` and `flag`, I'll be indexing them to $[0, n-1]$ where $n$ is the number of categories in the feature.

As for the numerical data, I'll be standardizing them using the Student's t-statistic $z = \dfrac{x - \mu}{\sigma}$.